# How to use turn:lanes in osm to find lane connectivity on intersection

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium

In osm,

Way A has nodes [n1, n2]

Way B has nodes [n2, n3]

Way C has nodes [n3, n4]

Way D has nodes [n4, n5]

[image]

coordinates - 1.28657, 103.8452

Way A has traffic "turn:lanes"=>"left|left;through|through|through|through;right|right"

Way B has traffic "turn:lanes"=>"left|left;through|through|through|through;right|right"

Way C and D do not have turn:lanes.

How to determine that the last lane of B Way also connects to D? Because there is no relation between B and D and C doesn't have any turn:lanes information.
I also looked at relations like route and connectivity from pbf file but didn't find anything. If I want to have lane connectivity of this intersection then how can I do it?

Comment: Questions that are this specific on OSM data can also (probably even better) be asked on the new(ish) OSM community website at https://community.openstreetmap.org/ .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The connectivity of lanes within an intersection is a very complex and intellectual problem, sometimes having no unambiguous solutions (in general case). But on the basis of OSM data it is possible to build a model of internal connections in the intersection.
Here is for example your picture, on the left is road visualization from OSM, on the right is road object detailing with accuracy up to the lane.